# How to re-create root user with IAM on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I don't have a team and I don't want to create limited scope users to access the console, apart from programmatic accesses that my code uses. However logging in with root is cumbersome as they ask for a captcha all the time. This results in not checking my billing regularly enough. I'd go as far as getting a paid captcha solver extension, it's so bad. So I want to create essentially a root user that has all the capabilities, but as an IAM user so it doesn't ask for a captcha. I know it's not best practice, but again I'm not part of an organization where any of it would matter. This doesn't work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the trouble you face is your IAM users can not access the Billing page.

You need to enable this first: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html and then create an IAM account with Administrator policy.

Comment: Oh yes, that was it! They hide that little Edit button very well, almost could not find it but I encountered that setting before, got lost why trying to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully I can help you